# detect if certain characters are typed within a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to determine if a user had typed a particular set of characters within a particular duration of time.

I made something that works, I suppose, but I know it isn't very good because it uses the global variable toMatch. I declared it with setInterval without the `var` keyword. Though the idea of scope is confusing for me I am trying to learn and I wonder if someone could offer a better way to do this?

```
//set the toMatch array equal to the character codes for the word 'test'
//reset it to its original value every 2seconds
var matchTime = setInterval(function(){ console.log('toMatch reset'); toMatch = [84,69, 83, 84];}, 2000);


document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){

   var key = e.which;
   findMatches(key);

});

function findMatches(key){

    //if the key is in the first position in the array, remove it
    if (key == toMatch[0]){
      toMatch.shift();

    }
      console.log(toMatch);

  //if all shifted out, clear the interval
  if (toMatch.length == 0 ) {
    window.clearInterval(matchTime);
    alert('typed \'test\' within two seconds');
  }

}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ujijat/3/edit)

Thank you

Comment: Why can't it be defined in `findMatches`?

Comment: @Nicholas what is the use of using array.shift() then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function listenForWord(word) {
    word = word.toUpperCase(); // event char codes are in upper case
    var counter = 0,
        time = 0;
    // I used jQuery, you could also use addEventListener but don't
    // forget to use attachEvent so it works in all browsers!
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        // Because the code is inside a function, the variable
        // word is available at this level but is not global
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        if (currentTime - time > 1000) {
            // If the user waits more than 1 second to type the next letter
            // The counter is reset, I'm not sure if this is what you want!
            counter = 0;
        }
        var character = word.charCodeAt(counter),
            first = word.charCodeAt(0);
        if (character == e.which) {
            counter++;
        } else if (character == first) {
            counter = 1;
        } else {
            counter = 0;
        }
        if (counter == word.length) {
            counter = 0;
            alert("You typed " + word + " fast enough");
        }
        time = currentTime;
    });
}

listenForWord("test");
// You could potentially call this function with other words
// And it will work
```

Note that my code does not have a `setInterval` call - because in reality you only need to check if the user has typed in the correct word any time he actually presses a key, no need to do any sort of reset on an interval.

This is not exactly the same as yours because it allows a user up to 4 seconds to type in a 4 letter word (no more than 1 second between each key typed).

If you want to test that they have typed all 4 characters within a set 2 second time limit, you could reformulate the logic to instead have the time stored when the first key is pressed - then compare the current time with that time rather than the time from the last key press.

Answer (score 0):

If your main question is how to avoid global variables then a simple answer would be to look into the Immediately-invoked function expression(IIFE). Ben Alman has a good article here: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

It basically encapsulates all of your variables/functions into their own scope and invokes itself right away. You can apply it to your code with minimal changes.

```
//Begin IIFE
(function(){
    //declare toMatch variable inside IIFE scope - prevents it from polluting the global scope
    var toMatch;
    //set the toMatch array equal to the character codes for the word 'test'
    //reset it to its original value every 2seconds
    var matchTime = setInterval(function(){ 
        console.log('toMatch reset'); 
        toMatch = [84,69, 83, 84];
    }, 2000);

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
         var key = e.which;
         findMatches(key);
    });

    function findMatches(key){

        //if the key is in the first position in the array, remove it
        if (key == toMatch[0]){
            toMatch.shift();
        }
        console.log(toMatch);

        //if all shifted out, clear the interval
        if (toMatch.length == 0 ) {
            window.clearInterval(matchTime);
            alert('typed \'test\' within two seconds');
        }

    };
})();


console.log(window.toMatch) // now toMatch isn't a global variable
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I suppose my main goal is not to avoid global variables. I can just recognize them as a symptom of their probably being larger problems. I first tried with an immediate function, but got errors about it `toMatch` being undefined...for a couple seconds...then it seemed to work. Odd..